# Articles not printed in biblioagraphy while manuals ok

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a problem with my bibliography.
It works only with manual and not with article. 
I use TexMaker with BibLatex. When I compilate I do pdflatex+biblatex+pdflatex(x2) and my biblatex command is set on biber %.
In my .tex file I use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Interline setting
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}


\newpage
\printbibliography
%\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    %\bibitem{BSS82}
    %  Smiths Metal Centre,
    %  \emph{BS S82 Technical Datasheet,
     % 2nd Edition,
     % 1994.
%\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

and here is my .bib file

```
@manual{datasheet,
author = {Smiths Metal Centres},
title = {BS S82 Technical Datasheet},
year = {2019},
url = {https://www.smithmetal.com/pdf/special/bar/s82.pdf},
}

@article{Ti1,
author = {Sahasrabudhe, H and Harrison, R and Carpenter, C and Bandyopadhyay, A},
title = {Stainless steel to titanium bimetallic structure using LENS},
journaltitle = {Additive Manufacturing},
year = {2015},
volume = {5},
pages = {1-8},
month = {January},
}

@article{Ti2,
author = {Reichardt, A and Dillon, R. P and Borgonia, JP and Shapiro, A A. and  McEnerney, B W. and Momose, T and Hosemann, P},
title = {Development and characterization of Ti-6Al-4V to 304L stainless steel gradient components fabricated with laser deposition additive manufacturing},
journaltitle = {Materials & Design},
year = {2016},
volume = {104},
pages = {404-413},
month = {August},
}


@manual{graninox,
author = {Pometon S.p.A},
title = {GRANINOX\textsuperscript{\textcopyright} Granules for blasting},

url = {https://www.pometon.com/media/product/family-attachment/graninox3_ZxO9sB8.pdf},
}

@article{tommaso,
author = {Maurizi Enrici, T and Mertens, A and Sinnaeve, M and Tchuindjang, JT},
title = {Elucidation of the solidification sequence of a complex graphitic HSS alloy under a combined approach of DTA and EBSD analyses},
journaltitle = {Journal of Thermal analysis and Calorimetry},
year = {in press},
}


@article{,
author = {Costa, L and Vilar, R and Réti, T},
title = {Simulating the effects of substrate pre-heating on the final structure of steel parts built by laser powder deposition},
journaltitle = {Solid Freeform Fabrication Symposium},
year = {2004},
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't show screenshots. Show a small complete example that we can compile to test the issue. And check if the biber reports some warning or error in the .blg-file.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. And I dont even know where to find problems with .blg

Comment: You can learn here how to make a minimal example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that. And regarding the .blg: it should be in the folder of your document. Simply open it with your editor as you would open a .tex file.

Comment: If you're using windows you may need to enable hidden extensions in order to find the file with the `.blg` ending as Windows associates `.blg` with something unrelated to bitbex/biber log files.

Comment: I did the minimal example (I edited my initial post)

Comment: Your minimal example is not complete. There is no \begin{document} command and you have no \cite commands, so the bibliography will be empty. Test your example to be sure that it works and shows your problem.

Comment: There's an obvious problem with `journaltitle = {Materials & Design},` that should be `journaltitle = {Materials \& Design},`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few fixes to the `.bib` entries:

1. “Corporate authors” such as `Smiths Metal Centres` should be braced
2. `Materials & Design` should be `Materials \& Design`
3. a key for one entry was missing, I added `costa`
4. `year={in press}` is invalid
5. the format for initials was inconsistent
6. parts that should not be subject to lowercasing should be braced

After the fixes I get

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@manual{datasheet,
author = {{Smiths Metal Centres}},
title = {{BS} {S82} {Technical} Datasheet},
year = {2019},
url = {https://www.smithmetal.com/pdf/special/bar/s82.pdf},
}

@article{Ti1,
author = {Sahasrabudhe, H. and Harrison, R. and Carpenter, C. and Bandyopadhyay, A.},
title = {Stainless steel to titanium bimetallic structure using {LENS}},
journaltitle = {Additive Manufacturing},
year = {2015},
volume = {5},
pages = {1-8},
month = {1},
}

@article{Ti2,
author = {Reichardt, A. and Dillon, R. P. and Borgonia, J. P. and 
          Shapiro, A. A. and  McEnerney, B. W. and Momose, T. and Hosemann, P.},
title = {Development and characterization of {Ti-6Al-4V} to {304L} stainless steel
         gradient components fabricated with laser deposition additive manufacturing},
journaltitle = {Materials \& Design},
year = {2016},
volume = {104},
pages = {404-413},
month = {8},
}


@manual{graninox,
author = {{Pometon S.p.A}},
title = {{GRANINOX}\textsuperscript{\normalfont\textcopyright} Granules for blasting},
url = {https://www.pometon.com/media/product/family-attachment/graninox3_ZxO9sB8.pdf},
}

@article{tommaso,
author = {Maurizi Enrici, T. and Mertens, A. and Sinnaeve, M. and Tchuindjang, J. T.},
title = {Elucidation of the solidification sequence of a complex graphitic {HSS}
         alloy under a combined approach of {DTA} and {EBSD} analyses},
journaltitle = {Journal of Thermal analysis and Calorimetry},
year = 2020,
note = {In press},
}


@article{costa,
author = {Costa, L. and Vilar, R. and Réti, T.},
title = {Simulating the effects of substrate pre-heating on the final
         structure of steel parts built by laser powder deposition},
journaltitle = {Solid Freeform Fabrication Symposium},
year = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

where I used `filecontents` just for making the example self-contained; the file name is changed in order to not clobber my files. You can (and should) use a separate file with the name you prefer.

Running LaTeX and Biber in the usual way yields

[image]

Comment: Omg it works !! thank you so much you saved my day